# c:\Windows\System32\java.exe default cert store location?

Tags: windows-7, java

I have not set `java_home` and I need to know where the `c:\Windows\System32\java.exe` file points to.
I have several JDKs and JREs on my system.

The reason is that I am trying to connect via SSL to some server and it works in Netbeans after I export the certificate in the appropriate JRE (which I can see via Netbeans options)

However, when I connect via command-line, I get an SSL error. I tried adding the certificate to all my JREs but I cannot get it to work. I think it is a problem that this Windows shortcut points to some place I overlooked.

Is there an easy way to find out which JRE is the default one?

[EDIT] Or rather I need to find the location of the default keystore in the default JRE.

[EDIT] My problem is elaborated below:

the following two give SSL error:

```
"c:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" -cp myjar.jar mypackage.myclass 
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" -cp myjar.jar mypackage.myclass
```

The following two work

```
"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin\bin\java.exe" -cp myjar.jar mypackage.myclass 
"c:\Program Files (x86)\jdk1.6.0_24\bin\jre6\bin\java.exe" -cp myjar.jar mypackage.myclass
```

I have exported the certificate using all four commands:

```
"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin\bin\keytool.exe" -import -alias myalias -file mycertfile
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin\bin\keytool.exe" -import -alias myalias -file mycertfile
"c:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\bin\keytool.exe" -import -alias myalias -file mycertfile
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\bin\keytool.exe" -import -alias myalias -file mycertfile
```

So it seems that the keytool uses a different store than `java.exe`.

would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: This could also be a problem: c:\Windows

Comment: Maybe you're 64 and 32 bit java version got somewhat mixed up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution. Thanks to [this link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v5r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.itim.infocenter.doc/tsk/tsk_ic_security_ssl_configtruststore.html).

It mentioned the location of the keystore. Surprisingly it took a bit of Googling.

The location is `jre6\lib\security\cacerts`

so I had to use the following command to import the certificate:

```
 keytool.exe -import -alias myalias -file mycertfile -keystore "c:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\security\cacerts"
```

Comment: Hi Jus12, I executed the above command but I am getting an error message like "keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_77\lib\security\mycertfile.cer (The system cannot find the file specified)" even I have the cer file in the same security folder. Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the "Java Application Runtimes Setting" from the Java tab of the Java Control Panel.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/jcp.html

From this tab, you can disable/enable any running version and you can see what is the current system JVM version...